# How to retrieve Gitlab environments variables to be used in gatsby-*.js files

Tags: reactjs, api, gitlab, environment-variables, gatsby

I have on gitlab environment variables secret api tokens, that I want to securely load in my project to be used in the *gatsby-*.js* files. I do not have or want to use *.env* files. According to various sources, I should be able to use my env variables just like this : `process.env.TOKEN`, but it does not work. I tried multiple Gatsby plugins, I tried having the prefix `GATSBY_` to my env variables on gitlab, yet it still doesn't work.
What I was able to do for now is to retrieve their values in my **gitlab-ci.yml** file like this :
`TOKEN: "${GATSBY_TOKEN}"`

where I can echo them in my build stage, So I don't know if the value is accesible in my yml file locally or it only becomes accesible when the pipeline is launched on gitlab. My question is it possible to pass them down to my gatsby-*.js files ? Or is there another solution entirely to the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to various sources, I should be able to use my env variables
> just like this : `process.env.TOKEN`

That is not how environment variables are supposed to work.

If you don't want to use `.env` files your only chance is setting them in the running commands, `gatsby develop` as well as `gatsby build`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "SOME_ENV_VAR=someValue gatsby develop",
   }
```

From now on, `SOME_ENV_VAR` will be exposed to be used in your code.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the better way to do this is to use a .env file, and not rely on gitlab environment variables at all, right ?

Comment: Both ways. Since `.env` files should be ignored in the `.gitignore` to avoid leaks, hence they won't be updated to the repo but they should exist as well in the server (if you use pipelines for example) or locally if you are developing

Comment: This has been very helpful, thank you ! One last question, what can I expect, in terms of lack of security, using .env files to store sensible data such as an api token ?

Comment: There won't be any leak or lack of security as long as those files are ignored or tracked. The tokens will only be available locally or in the server (i.e: AWS, GitLab, etc), no one can access them so you're safe. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting the answer to close the topic

Comment: Sotrry but I have to bother you once more, so locally all is going well, my token is safely held in the .env.development file, but my pipeline keeps failing because it doesn't recognize the process.env.TOKEN server side, even though it is correctly declared as a gitlab env variable. Any idea how to make it work ?

Comment: Nope, sorry, this belongs to GitLab specifics :/